# Can't understand uTorrent Transfer Protocol 'extension' option in header

Tags: tcp, udp, bittorrent

i'm trying to understand how a uTP header is structured and how it handles traffic and congestion and all that.

While going through the documentation [here](http://www.bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0029.html) i couldn't quite wrap my head around what the 'extension' portion of the header worked. Here is the header:

```
0       4       8               16              24              32
+-------+-------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
| type  |  ver  | extension     | connection_id                 |
+-------+-------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
| timestamp_microseconds                                        |
+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
| timestamp_difference_microseconds                             |
+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
| wnd_size                                                      |
+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
| seq_nr                        | ack_nr                        |
+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
```

And this is the portion talking about the 'extension' field:

```
extension

The type of the first extension in a linked list of extension headers. 0 means no extension.

There is currently one extension:

    Selective acks

Extensions are linked, just like TCP options. If the extension field is non-zero, immediately following the uTP header are two bytes:

0               8               16
+---------------+---------------+
| extension     | len           |
+---------------+---------------+

where extension specifies the type of the next extension in the linked list, 0 terminates the list. And len specifies the number of bytes of this extension. Unknown extensions can be skipped by simply advancing len bytes.
```

How do linked lists come into all of this?
It is (to me) implying further available extensions?

Answer (score 0):

The packet header contains a descriptor (1 byte) for the first extension header or a sentinel value of 0.
The first extension in turn would contain an extension header (this time 2 bytes since it includes a length) and the extension body. The header would again point to the next extension or be a sentinel value.

It is a linked list because the Nth extension header links to the N+1th extension.

This is a common pattern to insert a variable amount of extensions between a fixed-layout packet header and the main payload. E.g. [IPv6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_packet#Extension_headers) and [TCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#TCP_segment_structure) use very similar mechanisms.

Comment: "2 bytes" <- Wrong It's 1 byte

Comment: @Encombe an extension descriptor contains both the type and the length, 1 byte each.

Comment: You wrote "The *packet header*..."- The 20 bytes *packet header* has a 1 byte extension field. Only if that field value is non-zero, a 2 bytes *extension header* will follow after the *packet header*.